# Why JSF separates more than other MVC framework the view from the model?

Tags: jsf, view, model

Hy,

I have read many time that JSF separates more than other MVC framework the view from the model/business logic and I dont really understand why. I mean, if I have a non JSF application and I have a servlet and a JSP page; the servlet does the business logic and pass some message to the JSP page which shows it to the user;here I am not mixing any businnes logic with the view, so why with JSF I get more separation? could you show me a little example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you just have a servlet and a veiw that combining "M" and "C". I use servlets as something that you go through to get to the model and vice versa. Servlets are a good definitive controller to separate the view from the model.

Also, what's wrong with a few more layers? :D

Comment: In a sense, I do. However, my personal preference is to abstract out as much as possible. :)